# Java - Annotation processor - method process not called

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I am trying to implement `AnnotationProcessor`. I am following [this tutorial](http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101).

I am able to debug the annotation processor, and the debugger goes to methods: `init`, `getSupportedAnnotationTypes`, `getSupportedOptions` ,`getSupportedSourceVersion` but it does not go to `process` method.

I was unable to find something useful on the internet. Could you please tell me why is this happening and how to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Share some code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just found out that in order to run the `process` method. At least one element must be annotated with an annotation that was set in `getSupportedAnnotationTypes`.

Comment: I did the same, but still process method is not calling